# Trying to update Date and Time in a loop

Tags: java, loops, date, time

I want to print and update the date and time simultaneously. The following code only takes the time once and prints the same time 40 times. How can I update the time while printing it?

```
public class Dandm {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String time = df.format(date);
        int i;
        for (i = 40; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(date);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Date is just a representation of a point in time, so it doesn't change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `System.out.println(date);` with `System.out.println(new Date());`

The problem is, when you do `Date date = new Date();` then `date` value doesn't change in the loop. You need a new date every time, so you should create a `new Date()` object every time.

Edit based on the comments (To get date as a string with only time):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");  
for(i = 40; i > 0; i--){
    Date date = new Date();
    String str = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(str);

    try{Thread.sleep(500);}
    catch (InterruptedException e){}
}
```

Comment: @Hooga You may click on the tick mark beside the answer to mark it as an answer.

Comment: How can i get the time in a string? I want to make it so if the time = 00 or a new hour, another action happens.

Comment: @Hooga If you just want Date in String, then it has a `toString()` method which you can use. `String s = date.toString()`

Comment: How do I get the SimpleDateFormat to only print the time?

Comment: No, @Hooga use a SimpleDateFormat, to format the date/time the way you want it. However, you can use getHour on the Date object, but you probably should be use LocalDateTime instead

Comment: How can I add the simple date format into the 'System.out.pintln(new Date());' ?

Comment: Do `Date date = new Date();` in the loop and then something like `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
   String str = sdf.format(date);`

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778222/format-a-datetime-string-to-time-only @Hooga

Comment: @Hooga Edited the answer, please see.

Comment: I think MadProgrammer meant to say [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) (not LocalDateTime) if you care only about time-of-day and not the date. Part of the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating your object one time only, once your object is created it acquires its properties:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

If you want to update your time along side printing it, then either you would create the object within the loop like this:

```
for (i = 40; i > 0; i--) {
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(date);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){}
}
```

Or just create an anonymous `Date` object in the print function.

```
for (i = 40; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(new Date());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){}
}
```